# why the control is not putting the value in variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a code for searching a word "To be Uploaded" in a first cell of every row.

```
lastrow = tmpSheet.Cells(tmpSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set Foundcell = tmpSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Find(What:="To be Uploaded")
```

it searched the keyword & put it on Foundcell but in a excel file where I am applying it , having the "To be Uploaded" on 12th row ,but not putting the value in Foundcell. What is the possibilities that it not putting the value?
it showing nothing after debugging.

[image]

control is giving the 12 value in lastrow, but still it's not putting in Foundcell.

How can I find the word by trimming up (ignores all the spaces if there is any)?
control is getting some extra spaces in cell but I am comparing it with less space word, so error is coming. There is 2 spaces b/w To & be, that's why control is not getting the same.

Comment: There are a whole load of other parameters to the `Find` method and they persist between calls to Find, both in code and in the UI, so you really should specify them each time.

Comment: didn't get..... in excel it is "TO BE UPLOADED" so it should find the same .  means the value "to be uploaded" should put in Founcell. Isn't it?
it is working for some but not for  some.

Comment: As I said, there are other parameters you should specify - eg: `Set Foundcell = tmpSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Find(What:="To be Uploaded", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)`

Comment: actually I need just to match that keyword... so suggest me what should I use. I don't have any idea on the rest parameter what u have mentioned.

Comment: have you looked at the method and what the parameters mean? If you read up on it, it will be very clear what it means and how you can use it to meet your needs...Here's a link to read ... Look at Find Method as it Applies to a Range Object ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195730(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: As in Foundcell it's getting "To be uploaded " but I am finding the "To be uploaded" , that's why it's showing nothing matched.
"......ded " means after ded there is a space which is not match to searched word(no space) . So is there any trim method can be used in searching.
I have gone through the link but didn't find any trim parameter.

Comment: In that case change `LookAt:=xlWhole` to `LookAt:=xlPart` as long as you don't have other cells that include that text.

Comment: I have used  LookAt:=xlPart but still it's not taking

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. Note that comparison is Case sensitive

```
Sub FindCell()
    Dim rows, LastRow As Integer


    With Sheets("tmpSheet")
    LastRow = .Cells(.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "To Be Uploaded" Then
                ' Do your Stuff
                ' I assume you want the address
                MsgBox .Cells(i, 1).Address
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: As in Foundcell it's getting "To be uploaded " but I am finding the "To be uploaded" , that's why it's showing nothing matched. "......ded " means after ded there is a space which is not match to searched word(no space) . So is there any trim method can be used in searching. I have gone through the link but didn't find any trim parameter

Comment: @ksrds change the if loop as if rtrim(.cells(i,1).value) = "To be uploaded" then

Comment: Trim is used to ignore only space before the first & after the last alphabet. It is not used to ignore the space between the words.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proper use of the `.Find()`, the second part might not be interesting for you, but at least you'll know how it is done properly if you want to keep loop on it.

Take a look at this :

```
Sub test_ksrds()

Dim FirstAddress As String, _
    LastRow As Long, _
    FoundCell As Range

With tmpSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set FoundCell = .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Find(What:="To be Uploaded")

    .Range("A2").Activate
    With .Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        'First, define properly the Find method
        Set FoundCell = .Find(What:="To be Uploaded", _
                    After:=ActiveCell, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)

        'If there is a result, keep looking with FindNext method
        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = FoundCell.Address
            Do
                '--- Let's say you want to set the value to 1 in column D if you found the value in column A
                FoundCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = 1
                Set FoundCell = .FindNext(FoundCell)
            'Look until you find again the first result
            Loop While Not FoundCell Is Nothing And FoundCell.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If

    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Should show him how to dim and set tmpSheet.  Also no need for the Activate or ActiveCell

Comment: @chris : what u want to say... didn't det

Comment: finally got the point that there is no method who search the keyword by trimming up between the words.I have to use alternate method only.. like looping etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I have also included some lines to print partial results in the `Immediate Window`, which is opened at the end. Please refer to the comments in the code.

```
Sub Rng_FindMethod()
Dim tmpSheet As Worksheet, pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim FoundCell As Range, LastRow As Long

Rem Somehow you should have set these objects in your original Procedure
Rem Setting them here for testing purposes
With ThisWorkbook
    Set tmpSheet = .Worksheets(1)
    Set pasteSheet = .Worksheets(2)
End With

Rem New variable
Dim sFnd1st As String

    With tmpSheet   'use [With] to perform several statements on the same object
    'see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264723(v=office.15).aspx
: .Activate 'Activate the worksheet to run the test

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  'use period [.] to refer to the properties of the object working [With]

: Rem Printing partial results for debugging - REMOVE WHEN FINAL!
: Debug.Print vbLf
: Debug.Print String(3, vbLf)
: Debug.Print "LastRow: ", LastRow

        If LastRow <> 1 Then
            With .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1))

                Rem Activate last cell of the range to start the search from the 1st cell (due to [After:=ActiveCell])
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Activate

                Rem Search range for partial matches (due to [LookAt:=xlPart])
                Set FoundCell = .Find(What:="To be Uploaded", After:=ActiveCell, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                Rem Validate Search Results
                If Not (FoundCell Is Nothing) Then

                    Rem Set address of first match found use later to validate completeness
                    sFnd1st = FoundCell.Address

                    Rem Run action with finding & reiterate search
                    Do

: Rem Printing partial results for debugging - REMOVE WHEN FINAL!
: Debug.Print "FoundCell: ", FoundCell.Address, "[" & FoundCell.Value2 & "]"

                        Rem Action on search results
                        tmpSheet.Rows(FoundCell.Row).EntireRow.Copy
                        pasteSheet.Rows(pasteSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False

                        Rem Find next match
                        Set FoundCell = .FindNext(After:=FoundCell)

                    Rem Validate Search Results
                    Loop While FoundCell.Address <> sFnd1st

    End If: End With: End If: End With

: Rem Opens the Immediate window to see results posted for debugging - REMOVE WHEN FINAL!
: SendKeys "^g": Stop

End Sub
```

Comment: hard to understand by me .... can you please elaborate it by dividing some piece that what those are doing....?

Comment: Have you tried? It's working? What parts do you have problems to understand?